# Need help with merging two data collections

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, union, intersection

I need to retrieve all items from two lists that contains a given value.

Example:

```
var list1 = {
    new Dummy(){ Name = "Dummy1", Number = 1 },
    new Dummy(){ Name = "Dummy2", Number = 2 },
    new Dummy(){ Name = "Dummy3", Number = 3 }
};

var list2 = {
    new Dummy(){ Name = "Dummy4", Number = 4 },
    new Dummy(){ Name = "Dummy5", Number = 2 },
    new Dummy(){ Name = "Dummy6", Number = 6 }
};

var list3 = GetAllDummiesWithNumbersContainedInBothLists();
```

I want list3 to contain **Dummy2** and **Dummy5**, since both have the same number.

How do i do this? It should be simple but i cant figure it out...

Comment: Great resource for LINQ references...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your requirements are, but something like this perhaps?

```
var commonIds = list1.Select(d => d.Number)
                     .Intersect(list2.Select(d => d.Number));

var commonIdsSet = new HashSet<int>(commonIds);

var list3 = list1.Concat(list2)
                 .Where(d => commonIdsSet.Contains(d.Number))
                 .ToList();
```

if you can clarify the exact requirements (do the results need to be grouped by the`Number`, Is`Number`unique for an item within a list etc.), we can provide better solutions.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you:

```
(from dummy1 in list1
join dummy2 in list2 on dummy1.Number equals dummy2.Number
from dummy in new[] { dummy1, dummy2 }
select dummy)
.Distinct()
```

This pairs matching dummies into the same scope, then flattens out the set so you get all of the matches in one sequence. The `Distinct` at the end ensures that each dummy appears exactly once even if either list contains repeated numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list3 = list1.Where(d => list2.Select(d2 => d2.Number).Contains(d.Number))
    .Union(list2.Where(d2 => list1.Select(d => d.Number).Contains(d2.Number)));
```

Comment: Not quite. That returns a `bool`.

Comment: @Ahmad - Yeah. I had two different answers merged together and forgot to change the last bit. Done.

Comment: @Ani - Yes, it would. Needed to Union the results looking the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more!

```
var list3 = list1
  .SelectMany(x => list2
   .SelectMany(y => 
    (y.Number == x.Number) ? new [] { x, y } : new Dummy[]{}
   )
  );
```

Comment: I freely admit, it is probably not the best, but Justin posted my original answer first so I felt compelled to discover another way!